# curl_setopt() API Deprecated Error

Tags: php, facebook

Found this error when using the upload method in the Facebook PHP SDK with PHP 5.5.0. This is an easy workaround until Facebook decide to pull their finger out and update the SDK.

This is the type of error you will receive when trying to upload an image or video with PHP 5.5.0:

```
curl_setopt(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead
```

The fix was posted by someone here: http://snippetrepo.com/snippets/deprecated-curl-setopt-fix-in-facebook-php-sdk

Is this fixed by Facebook yet?

Answer (score 0):

Found this error when using the upload method in the Facebook PHP SDK with PHP 5.5.0. This is an easy workaround until Facebook decide to pull their finger out and update the SDK

This is the type of error you will receive when trying to upload an image or video with PHP 5.5.0:

> curl_setopt(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead

To apply the fix navigate to your base_facebook.php file and search for this:

```
if ($this->getFileUploadSupport()){
    $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $params;
} else {
    $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query($params, null, '&');
}
```

And replace with the fix below:

```
if ($this->getFileUploadSupport()){
  if(!empty($params['source'])){
     $nameArr = explode('/', $params['source']);
     $name    = $nameArr[count($nameArr)-1]; 
     $source  = str_replace('@', '', $params['source']);
     $size    = getimagesize($source); 
     $mime    = $size['mime'];
     $params['source'] = new CurlFile($source,$mime,$name);
  }

  if(!empty($params['image'])){
     $nameArr = explode('/', $params['image']);
     $name    = $nameArr[count($nameArr)-1]; 
     $image   = str_replace('@', '', $params['image']);
     $size    = getimagesize($image); 
     $mime    = $size['mime'];
     $params['image'] = new CurlFile($image,$mime,$name);
  }
  $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $params;
} else {
    $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query($params, null, '&');
}
```

http://snippetrepo.com/snippets/deprecated-curl-setopt-fix-in-facebook-php-sdk